# whether - followed by positive or negative form?

Tags: meaning, grammar, ambiguity

''Pascal attempted the experiment of
seeing whether, with the aid of the most incisive knowledge,
everyone could not be brought to despair: the experiment miscarried,
to his twofold despair.'' 
[Daybreak: Thoughts on the Prejudices of Morality](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FBFNTQlSa-8C&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=Pascal%20attempted%20the%20experiment%20of%20seeing%20whether,%20with%20the%20aid%20of%20the%20most%20incisive%20knowledge,&source=bl&ots=l85c2rxEcM&sig=KbUL7Ot8XCEFmJa8sRZ-pWCBF_Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAmoVChMIpdHmgejoyAIVAekaCh1ENQ_7#v=onepage&q=Pascal%20attempted%20the%20experiment%20of%20seeing%20whether%2C%20with%20the%20aid%20of%20the%20most%20incisive%20knowledge%2C&f=false)
 By Friedrich Nietzsche

What exactly does the phrase from above mean? That Pascal tried to find out if he, somehow, could stop people from despairing, or if he could get all of them to despair?

Comment: When you quote some text, please can you acknowledge the source, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> What exactly does the phrase from above mean? That Pascal tried to find out if he, somehow, could stop people from despairing, or if he could get all of them to despair?

The latter.

Of course we have to rely on the translators and hope that they correctly presented  Nietzsche's words. There is a useful discussion of Pascal's attitude [here.](http://www.thegospelcoalition.org/article/pascals-method-for-presenting-the-christian-faith)